# WAMP 64x with apps doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, apache, 64-bit, wamp

I got a project running for a client with PHP 5.3.13 and when I moved the whole site including the databases from their servers to my WAMP server some PHP functions don't work. So at first I write some new PHP functions, but now it seems like it will be like write a whole new page. So what I want is to use PHP version 5.3.13 on my WAMP server.

I read on WAMP's page that you could use apps or addons so I downloaded both Apache 2.2.2 and PHP 5.3.1 but now it is a red icon on both. When I try to switch PHP to a different it says that my Apache is not compatible with my PHP, or when I try to switch my Apache it says the same.

So I search the web, and it seems to be that my WAMP install is 64x version with PHP 5.4.12 and Apache 2.4.4. So I am thinking if I can install a new WAMP server on the same HDD or will it destroy something?

Otherwise is there some other way around this?

Comment: Don't worry about not having perfect English, but if you can spell-check your posts prior to submitting them, that helps a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the ADONS you have to install WAMPServer 32bit, as all the adons are compiled 32bit.

32bit is a better idea anywhay currently as not all extension have a 64bit equivalent.

So install WAMPServer 2.2e and that will make it easier to install PHP ADDON versions.